Setup Tomcat Datasource to connect to a MySQL Socket enabled connection
Actually, I had a Datasource connection based in TCP.
<Resource name="testDB" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
  username="test"
  password="test"
  driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
  url="jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/test?useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=utf8"
  maxTotal="15"
  maxIdle="7"
  validationQuery="Select 1 from dual"/>

I need to change it to work using MySQL socket, because I don't want TCP exposure of the database.
I tried different approaches but none of them worked. Examples I tried:
url="jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/test?useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=utf8&amp;socket=/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock"

or
url="jdbc:mysql:socket=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock:3306/yourDatabaseName?useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC"

None of this worked. Can anyone help me to resolve it? Thank you

first, jdbc only support host port connection, so com.mysql.jdbc.Driver can not do this thing.
maybe junixsocket is your need.
